# Creating a vpn profile and connencting (PPTP) with username and password in android programmatically

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I want to build an app that can connect with a single click of button which will create a vpn profile and connect to the vpn profile by parsig the username and password of the vpn server.
The code that is developed and modified is good to create and connect vpn but my vpn requires username and password to be entered so i want to do that programatically.
Here is my project

> VpnClient.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.VpnService;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VpnClient extends AppCompatActivity{
    public interface Prefs {
        String NAME = "connection";
        String SERVER_ADDRESS = "server.address";
        String SERVER_PORT = "server.port";
        String SHARED_SECRET = "shared.secret";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button disconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);

      //  final TextView serverAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        //final TextView serverPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.port);
       // final TextView sharedSecret = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secret);
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Prefs.NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String serverAddress = "";  !!I insert my vpnserver address in here which is my.vpnserver.com
        final String serverPort = "";  !!As server port i am using 1723 for PPTP connection

         connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prefs.edit()
                        .putString(Prefs.SERVER_ADDRESS,"")
                        .putString(Prefs.SERVER_PORT, "")
                        .putString(Prefs.SHARED_SECRET, "")
                        .commit();

                Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(VpnClient.this);

                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else {
                    onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
                }
            }
        });

        disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(getServiceIntent().setAction(MyVpnService.ACTION_DISCONNECT));
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
        if (result == RESULT_OK) {
            startService(getServiceIntent().setAction(MyVpnService.ACTION_CONNECT));
        }
    }
    private Intent getServiceIntent() {

        return new Intent(this, MyVpnService.class);
    }
}
```

> MyVpnService.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class MyVpnService extends andenter code hereroid.net.VpnService implements android.os.Handler.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = MyVpnService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String ACTION_CONNECT = "com.yaksh.vpn.START";
    public static final String ACTION_DISCONNECT = "com.yaksh.vpn.STOP";
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static class Connection extends Pair<Thread, ParcelFileDescriptor> {
        public Connection(Thread thread, ParcelFileDescriptor pfd) {
            super(thread, pfd);
        }
    }
    private final AtomicReference<Thread> mConnectingThread = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<Connection> mConnection = new AtomicReference<>();
    private AtomicInteger mNextConnectionId = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private PendingIntent mConfigureIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The handler is only used to show messages.
        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler(this);
        }
        // Create the intent to "configure" the connection (just start ToyVpnClient).
        mConfigureIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, VpnClient.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null && ACTION_DISCONNECT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            disconnect();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        } else {
            connect();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        disconnect();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message.what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (message.what != R.string.disconnected) {
            updateForegroundNotification(message.what);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void connect() {
        // Become a foreground service. Background services can be VPN services too, but they can
        // be killed by background check before getting a chance to receive onRevoke().
        updateForegroundNotification(R.string.connecting);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.connecting);
        // Extract information from the shared preferences.
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(VpnClient.Prefs.NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String server = prefs.getString(VpnClient.Prefs.SERVER_ADDRESS, "");
        final byte[] secret = prefs.getString(VpnClient.Prefs.SHARED_SECRET, "").getBytes();
        final int port;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(VpnClient.Prefs.SERVER_PORT, ""));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Bad port: " + prefs.getString(VpnClient.Prefs.SERVER_PORT, null), e);
            return;
        }
        // Kick off a connection.
        startConnection(new VpnConnection(
                this, mNextConnectionId.getAndIncrement(), server, port, secret));
    }
    private void startConnection(final VpnConnection connection) {
        // Replace any existing connecting thread with the  new one.
        final Thread thread = new Thread(connection, "ToyVpnThread");
        setConnectingThread(thread);
        // Handler to mark as connected once onEstablish is called.
        connection.setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent);
        connection.setOnEstablishListener(new VpnConnection.OnEstablishListener() {
            public void onEstablish(ParcelFileDescriptor tunInterface) {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.connected);
                mConnectingThread.compareAndSet(thread, null);
                setConnection(new Connection(thread, tunInterface));
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    private void setConnectingThread(final Thread thread) {
        final Thread oldThread = mConnectingThread.getAndSet(thread);
        if (oldThread != null) {
            oldThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
    private void setConnection(final Connection connection) {
        final Connection oldConnection = mConnection.getAndSet(connection);
        if (oldConnection != null) {
            try {
                oldConnection.first.interrupt();
                oldConnection.second.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Closing VPN interface", e);
            }
        }
    }
    private void disconnect() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.disconnected);
        setConnectingThread(null);
        setConnection(null);
        stopForeground(true);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void updateForegroundNotification(final int message) {
        startForeground(1, new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_vpn)
                .setContentText(getString(message))
                .setContentIntent(mConfigureIntent)
                .build());
    }
}
```

> VpnConnection.java

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by Yaksh on 11/3/2017.
 */

public class VpnConnection implements Runnable{
    /**
     * Callback interface to let the {@link MyVpnService} know about new connections
     * and update the foreground notification with connection status.
     */
    public interface OnEstablishListener {
        void onEstablish(ParcelFileDescriptor tunInterface);
    }
    /** Maximum packet size is constrained by the MTU, which is given as a signed short. */
    private static final int MAX_PACKET_SIZE = Short.MAX_VALUE;
    /** Time to wait in between losing the connection and retrying. */
    private static final long RECONNECT_WAIT_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3);
    /** Time between keepalives if there is no traffic at the moment.
     *
     * TODO: don't do this; it's much better to let the connection die and then reconnect when
     *       necessary instead of keeping the network hardware up for hours on end in between.
     **/
    private static final long KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15);
    /** Time to wait without receiving any response before assuming the server is gone. */
    private static final long RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20);
    /**
     * Time between polling the VPN interface for new traffic, since it's non-blocking.
     *
     * TODO: really don't do this; a blocking read on another thread is much cleaner.
     */
    private static final long IDLE_INTERVAL_MS = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(100);
    /**
     * Number of periods of length {@IDLE_INTERVAL_MS} to wait before declaring the handshake a
     * complete and abject failure.
     *
     * TODO: use a higher-level protocol; hand-rolling is a fun but pointless exercise.
     */
    private static final int MAX_HANDSHAKE_ATTEMPTS = 50;
    private final MyVpnService mService;
    private final int mConnectionId;
    private final String mServerName;
    private final int mServerPort;
    private final byte[] mSharedSecret;
    private PendingIntent mConfigureIntent;
    private OnEstablishListener mOnEstablishListener;
    public VpnConnection(final MyVpnService service, final int connectionId,
                         final String serverName, final int serverPort, final byte[] sharedSecret) {
        mService = service;
        mConnectionId = connectionId;
        mServerName = serverName;
        mServerPort= serverPort;
        mSharedSecret = sharedSecret;
    }
    /**
     * Optionally, set an intent to configure the VPN. This is {@code null} by default.
     */
    public void setConfigureIntent(PendingIntent intent) {
        mConfigureIntent = intent;
    }
    public void setOnEstablishListener(OnEstablishListener listener) {
        mOnEstablishListener = listener;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(getTag(), "Starting");
            // If anything needs to be obtained using the network, get it now.
            // This greatly reduces the complexity of seamless handover, which
            // tries to recreate the tunnel without shutting down everything.
            // In this demo, all we need to know is the server address.
            final SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(mServerName, mServerPort);
            // We try to create the tunnel several times.
            //       network is available.
            // Here we just use a counter to keep things simple.
            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 10; ++attempt) {
                // Reset the counter if we were connected.
                if (run(serverAddress)) {
                    attempt = 0;
                }
                // Sleep for a while. This also checks if we got interrupted.
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            Log.i(getTag(), "Giving up");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(getTag(), "Connection failed, exiting", e);
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private boolean run(SocketAddress server)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, IllegalArgumentException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor iface = null;
        boolean connected = false;
        // Create a DatagramChannel as the VPN tunnel.
        try (DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open()) {
            // Protect the tunnel before connecting to avoid loopback.
            if (!mService.protect(tunnel.socket())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
            }
            // Connect to the server.
            tunnel.connect(server);
            // For simplicity, we use the same thread for both reading and
            // writing. Here we put the tunnel into non-blocking mode.
            tunnel.configureBlocking(false);
            // Authenticate and configure the virtual network interface.
            iface = handshake(tunnel);
            // Now we are connected. Set the flag.
            connected = true;
            // Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(iface.getFileDescriptor());
            // Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(iface.getFileDescriptor());
            // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
            ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
            // Timeouts:
            //   - when data has not been sent in a while, send empty keepalive messages.
            //   - when data has not been received in a while, assume the connection is broken.
            long lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long lastReceiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // We keep forwarding packets till something goes wrong.
            while (true) {
                // Assume that we did not make any progress in this iteration.
                boolean idle = true;
                // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
                int length = in.read(packet.array());
                if (length > 0) {
                    // Write the outgoing packet to the tunnel.
                    packet.limit(length);
                    tunnel.write(packet);
                    packet.clear();
                    // There might be more outgoing packets.
                    idle = false;
                    lastReceiveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                // Read the incoming packet from the tunnel.
                length = tunnel.read(packet);
                if (length > 0) {
                    // Ignore control messages, which start with zero.
                    if (packet.get(0) != 0) {
                        // Write the incoming packet to the output stream.
                        out.write(packet.array(), 0, length);
                    }
                    packet.clear();
                    // There might be more incoming packets.
                    idle = false;
                    lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                // If we are idle or waiting for the network, sleep for a
                // fraction of time to avoid busy looping.
                if (idle) {
                    Thread.sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_MS);
                    final long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (lastSendTime + KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL_MS <= timeNow) {
                        // We are receiving for a long time but not sending.
                        // Send empty control messages.
                        packet.put((byte) 0).limit(1);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                            packet.position(0);
                            tunnel.write(packet);
                        }
                        packet.clear();
                        lastSendTime = timeNow;
                    } else if (lastReceiveTime + RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_MS <= timeNow) {
                        // We are sending for a long time but not receiving.
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Timed out");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e(getTag(), "Cannot use socket", e);
        } finally {
            if (iface != null) {
                try {
                    iface.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getTag(), "Unable to close interface", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }
    private ParcelFileDescriptor handshake(DatagramChannel tunnel)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // To build a secured tunnel, we should perform mutual authentication
        // and exchange session keys for encryption. To keep things simple in
        // this demo, we just send the shared secret in plaintext and wait
        // for the server to send the parameters.
        // Allocate the buffer for handshaking. We have a hardcoded maximum
        // handshake size of 1024 bytes, which should be enough for demo
        // purposes.
        ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        // Control messages always start with zero.
        packet.put((byte) 0).put(mSharedSecret).flip();
        // Send the secret several times in case of packet loss.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            packet.position(0);
            tunnel.write(packet);
        }
        packet.clear();
        // Wait for the parameters within a limited time.
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_HANDSHAKE_ATTEMPTS; ++i) {
            Thread.sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_MS);
            // Normally we should not receive random packets. Check that the first
            // byte is 0 as expected.
            int length = tunnel.read(packet);
            if (length > 0 && packet.get(0) == 0) {
                return configure(new String(packet.array(), 1, length - 1).trim());
            }
        }
        throw new IOException("Timed out");
    }
    private ParcelFileDescriptor configure(String parameters) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
        MyVpnService.Builder builder = mService.new Builder();
        for (String parameter : parameters.split(" ")) {
            String[] fields = parameter.split(",");
            try {
                switch (fields[0].charAt(0)) {
                    case 'm':
                        builder.setMtu(Short.parseShort(fields[1]));
                        break;
                    case 'a':
                        builder.addAddress(fields[1], Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        builder.addRoute(fields[1], Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        builder.addDnsServer(fields[1]);
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        builder.addSearchDomain(fields[1]);
                        break;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad parameter: " + parameter);
            }
        }
        // Create a new interface using the builder and save the parameters.
        final ParcelFileDescriptor vpnInterface;
        synchronized (mService) {
            vpnInterface = builder
                    .setSession(mServerName)
                    .setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent)
                    .establish();
            if (mOnEstablishListener != null) {
                mOnEstablishListener.onEstablish(vpnInterface);
            }
        }
        Log.i(getTag(), "New interface: " + vpnInterface + " (" + parameters + ")");
        return vpnInterface;
    }
    private final String getTag() {
        return VpnConnection.class.getSimpleName() + "[" + mConnectionId + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: any luck man? i am also searching same

Comment: No luck yet man.

Comment: Any luck ? i have been stuck on the same issue.